# Angular JS- testing with Protractor: how to get an element when element doesn't have a tag-name?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, element

I am developing a test suite for my AngularJS app using [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org) as my testing framework.

The app's menu is displayed at a fixed location across all pages of the site- when the user hovers the cursor over any of the buttons on the menu, the cursor changes to a pointer, to indicate that that button can be clicked. Each button in the menu represents a particular page of the app- if there are sub-pages belonging to a page when the user hovers the cursor over the menu button for that page, a sub-menu is displayed, with text-buttons for each of the sub-pages.

I am currently working on a test that will test the functionality of the menu- hovering the cursor over one of the buttons on the menu, checking that the sub-menu is displayed, and then hidden again when the cursor is no longer hovering over that menu button, checking that clicking any of the menu buttons/ sub-menu buttons take you to the right page, etc.

The HTML for the menu is written as follows:

```
<ul id="nav"
    class="nav"
    data-slim-scroll
    data-collapse-nav
    data-highlight-active>
    <li data-ng-mouseenter="setMenuTop($event)" ng-show="menu.pages.length > 0 || menu.upages.length > 0 || canCreatePage">
        <a href="#/pages" id="pagesMenuBtn" target="_self"><i class="ti-layers"></i><span data-i18n="Pages"></span></a>
        <ul class="text-capitalize">
            <li ng-repeat="page in menu.pages"><a href="#/{{page.location}}" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="{{page.title}}"></span></a></li>
            <li ng-repeat="upage in menu.upages">
                <div class="nav-menu-divider" data-ng-if="$index === 0"></div>
                <a href="#/{{upage.location}}" target="_self">
                    <i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="{{upage.title}}"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-ng-show="canCreatePage">
                <div class="nav-menu-divider"></div>
                <a href="#/pages/create" target="_self">
                    <i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="Create Page"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li data-ng-mouseenter="setMenuTop($event)">
        <a href="#/config" target="_self"><i class="ti-settings"></i><span data-i18n="Config"></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="page in menu.config"><a href="#/{{page.location}}" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="{{page.title}}"></span></a></li>
            <li ng-show="platform._id"><a ng-href="#/config/platform/{{platform._id}}" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="Platform"></span></a></li>
            <li ng-show="system._id"><a ng-href="#/config/system/{{system._id}}" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="System"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/config/user" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="Users"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/config/backup" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="Backup / Restore"></span></a></li>
            <li ng-show="systemActions.dateTime"><a href="#/config/systemtime" target="_self"><i class="ti-angle-right"></i><span data-i18n="Date / Time"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-footer">
        <span>{{currentTime.localTDZFormat}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As shown, there are two menu items which have 'sub-menus' associated with them.

I want to test that when the user hovers their cursor over one of the menu-items that have an associated sub-menu, the sub-menu is displayed correctly, and when the cursor leaves the menu-item, the sub-menu is no longer displayed: I have tried to do this with the following test:

```
it('should display the Pages menu', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(pagesMenuBtn).perform();
    expect(pageVarBrowserBtn.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    browser.actions().mouseMove(userCircle).perform();
    expect(pageVarBrowserBtn.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});
```

The variables used in this test are defined with:

```
var pagesMenuBtn = element(by.id('pagesMenuBtn'));
var pageVarBrowserBtn = element.all(by.id('menu.pages')).get(0);
var userCircle = element(by.id('icon-user-circle'));
```

The `pageVarBrowserBtn` is the first menu-item in the sub-menu displayed when the user hovers their cursor over the `pagesMenuBtn`.

Currently, when I run the test, the browser opens, navigates to the root page of my app, and hovers the cursor over the `pagesMenuBtn` element, so that the sub-menu is displayed (I can see it displayed in the browser window that was opened up by the test).

But, I then get an error in the console that says:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(CSS selector, *[id="menu.pages"])

I don't understand why I'm getting this error...? How can I get a single element from the sub-menu that's being displayed, in order to check that it is the correct item and that clicking it takes the user to the correct location? I can't specify the exact element's ID because it is being created by the `ng-repeat`, so that's why I'm trying to get it by its position/ array index - 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, There may be two reasons why you are getting the above error.

```
1. Either the locator you are using is wrong.
2. Your script is not waiting until the element is displayed in DOM.
```

In your case, you have mentioned a wrong locator as `element.all(by.id('menu.pages'))` because there is no element with id  `menu.pages` is present in your HTML.

Instead of using `element.all(by.id('menu.pages'))`, change it to `element.all(by.repeater('page in menu.pages')).get(0)` to get the 1st element from the menu list. Also kindly refer [Element locators in Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) to find the list of all available locating strategies that is supported by protractor.

Hope this might help solve your problem!

Comment: Brilliant, using `element.all(by.repeater('page in menu.pages')).get(0);` worked - really useful to know that `by.repeater` is how to access elements created by `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [element.all(locator).first()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) to get the first element form the selector